# cookies js - issue with navigate page

Tags: javascript, cookies

i have an issue with cookies in JS: i have a site with 3 pages and i want to create one cookie for all them. right know i have:

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function deleteCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, "", -1);
}
```

and i want to change language using this cookie. (controler in .net)

```
if (getCookie("_culture") == 'de') {
    $('#de_culture').attr("selected", "selected");
}
else if (getCookie("_culture") == 'en') {
    $('#en_culture').attr("selected", "selected");
}
$('#language-form').change(function () {
    var selectedOption = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    if (selectedOption == 'Deutsch') {

        deleteCookie("_culture");
        createCookie("_culture", "de", 30);
        location.reload(true);
    } else if (selectedOption == 'English') {

        deleteCookie("_culture");
        createCookie("_culture", "en", 30);
        location.reload(true);
    }    
});
```

on main page it works, using

```
var list = document.cookie;
console.log(list);
```

it display: _culture=de
but if i navigate to other page this code displays: _culture; _culture=de
and my controller see cookie with is null and do nothing; why is here two cookies? where is a bug?

Comment: Try to not delate the cookie with `deleteCookie("_culture");` before change it with new lang.

Comment: it change nothing. Still there is another _culture with null value

Comment: Ok, but is however useless. So, your code is correct.  `createCookie` and `getCookie ` create and get cookie with correct syntax. Maybe somewere in the other page (not in your main) you define like `null` the cookie. Or the other page has a different domain. There aren't any other thing. Try to create a cookie with an other name (manually in console) and check it in the other pages.

Answer (score 0):

You should set domain to your cookies to be readable in all your subdomains.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

> **domain** (Optional) - 
>   The domain from where the cookie will be readable. E.g., "example.com", ".example.com" (includes all subdomains) or "subdomain.example.com"; if not specified, defaults to the host portion of the current document location (string or null).

Comment: i try to set the domain but it didn help. still there is two cookies